# How do you set-up Logback on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, logback

I have a Java application that uses Logback for logging. And I want to start developing the same Java app on my Macbook.

I have some experience with Mac but not much. Is Logback compatible with Mac also? How to set-it up on the Mac?

any tips or pointers appreciated,thanks

Comment: Logback is a Java library as others, you don't need to do any special thing to use it on OSX. Just include the dependencies and run your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Fix path separators in logback configurations to direct slash '/'. This will work in all OSs (even in Windows).
- Provide write access for your application to log directory(ies).

Logback library is fully compatible with macos, so no additional actions or configurations required.

Comment: I need to look up the step "Provide write access for your application to log directory(ies).